# Is there a way to compile-time assert if a variable is a class, struct or a basic type in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, typechecking

I am trying to implement a template class that would be able to tell me if a variable is a class,structure or a basic type.

So far I've come with this:

```
template< typename T >
class is_class
{
private:
    template< typename X >
    static char ( &i_class( void(X::*)() ) )[1];
    //
    template< typename X >
    static char ( &i_class( X ) )[2];
public:
    static bool const val = sizeof( i_class< T >(0) ) == 1;
};
```

and ussage:

```
is_class< int >::val; // false
is_class< some_class_type >::val; // true
```

The problem is that now I need to write a blank void function in every class that could be used with this code.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: As an aside, why do you care whether it is a class or a struct? Anything could be a class or a struct. Actually if you choose not to rely on the default "private:" for class and "public:" for struct, and instead you write them explicitly, you could change all your classes to structs or vice versa without changing the meaning or behaviour of the code at all.

Comment: The reason for this check is that I have a template function that has most of the functionality the same for every type but there's a part that handles polymorphic classes differently than other types. I've solved the problem for checking if a class is polymorphic with a similar test as the one above ( in my case polymorphic classes must have a certain function that I look for in the test ). But that test doesn't compile if the variable given to the function is not a class type so I need to test before that at least if it's a class or not.

Comment: I actually haven't tried that test with a structure but it would make things easier for me to dismiss a structure in a previous test as it can't be polymorphic.

Comment: I would say structs can be polymorphic too, since the only difference is what I said - members public by default instead of private by default.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`is_class` is a member of the Boost.Type_Traits library. The implementation is probably similar to what you already have. You would use in in conjunction with `enable_if` to create the function if appropriate:

```
template <class T>
   typename enable_if_c<boost::is_class<T>::value>::type 
     foo() {  }
```

Or the equivalent:

```
template <class T>
   typename enable_if<boost::is_class<T>>::type 
     foo() {  }
```

The function `foo` is only generated if the type `T` is of class type.

The return value for the function, if it is generated, is the second parameter (omitted) to the `enable_if` template (the default is `void`).

Comment: Note that is_class relies on non-standard compiler support to distinguish between classes and unions, with the result that it is often erroneously true for unions. That doesn't stop it correctly distinguishing between class and fundamental types, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Use boost's [type traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

If it's only asserting during compile time, you could use `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT` and [Boost.TypeTraits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html) to check if types are suitable. If you want to enable a template for specific types, you may have success using Boost's [enable_if](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html).